# Django- specifying url in runserver

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to integrate social signon into a project, and am following along this tutorial: http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/.

Step #4 shows that the project requires a 'real url'. It appears you used to be able to specify a url when running `manage.py runserver example.com` (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14928)

However, on Django 1.6.5 this results in `CommandError: "example.com" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.`

What is the easiest way to run a local webserver so that my django project appears at whateverurl.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a unix-like OS, edit /etc/hosts and include:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

If you are on windows, look for `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Then you can use `python manage.py runserver example.com:80`

Note that external servers will not be able to call example.com, if the API you are testing requires the provider server to call this URL directly, you can only use this to test against a local provider.

Comment: This worked. Though, port 80 results in: Error: You don't have permission to access that port. Port 8000 worked beautifully.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. Only root can bind to ports below 1024, I guess that is why you got the error. Also, if you are running a local webserver, it is already bound to TCP/80.